# Select all except particular column in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive, spark-hive

I want to select all columns in a table except StudentAddress and hence I wrote following query:

```
select `(StudentAddress)?+.+` from student;
```

It gives following error in Squirrel Sql client.
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`(StudentAddress)?+.+`' given input columns

Comment: This syntax does not seem to be supported by Spark

Comment: Any workarounds?

Comment: What is the actual need?

Comment: I am joining multiple very wide tables so after performing one join, I need to drop one of the joined column to remove ambiguity for next join. Currently, I am specifying all the column names I want in select but functionality like except columns would be very flexible. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [drop()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#drop(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) method in the DataFrame API to drop a particular column and then select all the columns.

For example:

```
val df = hiveContext.read.table("student")
val dfWithoutStudentAddress = df.drop("StudentAddress")
```

Comment: The select("*") isn't necessary after the drop.

Answer (score 12):

Using **`spark sql`** try with

**`select * except(<columns to be excluded>) from tablename`**

**`Example:`**

```
select * from tmp
#+----+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|col4|
#+----+----+----+----+
#|a   |b   |c   |d   |
#+----+----+----+----+


#exclude col1,col2
select * except(col1,col2) from table_name
#+----+----+
#|col3|col4|
#+----+----+
#|c   |d   |
#+----+----+
```

Comment: any idea why when I try to do this I get:  Undefined function: 'except'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database

Comment: Which version of spark SQL is this function `except` supported? Because as of this writing, it doesn't exist in the latest version of Apache Spark (v3.5.0): https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/sql/index.html

Comment: `except`(to be more accurate, except clause) is supported only in Databricks Runtime 11.0 and above. See https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select.html. Open-Source Apache Spark doesn't support it as of 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but I recently run in a similar issue where I was required to swap a column.

My solution is for pyspark, but can easily implemented in other languages.

```py
df = df.select([df[col] for col in df.columns if col != 'StudentAddress'])
```

this tecnique comes very handy when you have to swap column with a computed one.

For instance:

```py
address = f.when(f.isnotnull(df.StudentAddress), df.StudentAddress).otherwise(f.lit('N/A'))
df = df.select([df[col] if col != 'StudentAddress' else address for col in df.columns])
```

Notice that in the list comprehension i return `df[col]` instead of just `col` to avoid ambiguities in case a previous join created more columns with the same name.